# nginx config multiple root doesn't work

Tags: nginx, httpd.conf, root

According to the config, `site.com` should open `html/web/index.php` by default, however `site.com/ticket` should open `html/ticket/index.php`. Both `ticket` and `web` folders located in `html`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    server_name  site.com;
    server_tokens off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }

    error_page   404              /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location /ticket {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/ticket;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

It opens `web/index.php`, however for `/ticket` it says `Not found`.

**UPDATE**

The above looks in `/usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/ticket/index.php`

I tried also

```
location /ticket {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

and

```
location /ticket {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/ticket;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Both configs look in `/usr/share/nginx/html/web/ticket/index.php`.

**It should look in `/usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/index.php`**

**I suppose, problem is in FastCGI**

**SOLUTION**

The problem was in FastCGI configurations

```
        try_files  $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: This isn't the full config is it? You have a "return" to https and `Strict-Transport-Security` so this site should be using https, yet there are no SSL configuration settings. So perhaps something in the rest of the config is causing the solutions below to not work

Comment: @Drifter104 yes, there are SSL configs, where I include certificates. How could it affect?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. I have tested it.

```
server {

    server_name  site.com;
     server_tokens off;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/web; 

   location / {
        index index.php;
    }

   location /ticket  {
        index index.php;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/;


    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }


    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    rewrite (.*) /ticket/index.php?$query_string;        

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

        }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }


}
```

Comment: No. I have reasons to not do that

Comment: Not a fix. It's a workaround for someone who can't do the configuration.

Comment: I have edited my answer with proper solution

Comment: What is php5-fpm.sock? I have php7

Comment: I tested with php-fpm and provide entire code. Just change the  fastcgi_pass  according to your PHP setup. The point is, you need to use alias to allow /ticket URL to look into to the somewhere outside of the root directory

Comment: @MukeshJagani It gives me a page with "No input file specified." written  when I open `/ticket`. What is that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `alias` directive. nginx does not add the full normalized URI after directory specified with `alias`, like it does with `root`.

So, your block would look like:

```
location /ticket {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/ticket;
    index index.php index.html index.html;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It looks in `/usr/share/nginx/html/web/ticket/index.php`. But should look in `/usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/index.php`

Comment: Updated the description, adding some more details

Comment: I think that both of our solutions should work. Upvoting this alternative.

Comment: But they don't. I copied all the config here. Please, look on updated info

Comment: Somehow, it takes `web` directory as default when I locate to `ticket`. I have no ideas...

Comment: Are you sure you really tried the `alias` exactly as written in my response? There is nothing where nginx could get the `/web` string in the middle of destination path if using this.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes! May be the `root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;` affected, which is written above the locations? If I remove `web`, it would work.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The problem is in Fast CGI. But I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the [`root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root). Inside `location`, it's still root relative rather than relative to that particular location.

> Sets the root directory for requests. For example, with the following
>   configuration
>
> ```
> location /i/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```
>
> The `/data/w3/i/top.gif` file will be sent in response to the
>   `/i/top.gif` request.

Therefore, you should have:

```
location /ticket/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Otherwise it's trying to access `/usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/ticket/index.php`, instead.

Comment: I tried this. It looks in `/usr/share/nginx/html/web/ticket/index.php`. But should look in `/usr/share/nginx/html/ticket/index.php`

Comment: Updated the description, adding some more details

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada change `location /ticket` to `location /ticket/`

Comment: @Drifter104  Didn't change anything

Comment: The problem is in FastCGI. But I don't know how to solve